# Image not getting displayed on click of search

Tags: php, html, image-loading

I have a GIF image stored at the root directory of my PHP application. There is a particular feature where on clicking a button the loading image is shown and once data is loaded the image disappears, however I have noticed that I get the 404 error in firebug and after I copy the path of the image in the firebug and paste it in a new tab the image gets loaded successfully!. I have also given 777 permission to the file. Server on which application is hosted is Linux (GoDaddy)

Comment: Show your code. Also take a look at a request for image in firebug, what's the url? And what's the right url?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try visiting the URL of the loading image it will work on other tab